# Why is webkit's transform making one element's borders unpredictable?

Tags: css, webkit, zurb-foundation

I've got two inputs, styled primarily by Zurb's [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/) framework. They're in a `.row.collapse` and each in a `.medium-6.columns` (these columns are 50% width, floated left, no margins). The inputs themselves are 100% wide within their containers. It's all pretty simple, and the Inspector and jQuery.css are all returning what I'd expect them to. But there's a border issue. Here's the gist of the CSS:

```
input {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  &.first {
    border-right-width: 0;
  }
}
```

This is to have the effect of collapsing the middle border. But for some reason, this `border-right-width: 0` is throwing Webkit (Chrome and Safari but not Firefox) off. The inspector shows 1px border, and the proper border-color. The white input background lines up properly with the second input (that is, there's room for the border), but there's no gray border. Maybe it's rendering transparent?

If I open this up on a retina display, it renders normally - proper borders on both. If I zoom in, the borders show up when it hits the "small" media query (mobile device sizes). But I can't make this border show up on a non-retina, desktop display in Chrome.

Here's how it looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

And here's how it looks in Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

To double-check, I used the Web Inspector to apply a simple border to the first element. It showed up fine (looked like the Firefox screenshot). Adding `border-right-width: 0` reintroduced the problem. It *seems* clear that that's the issue. But I don't know why?

It seems like `border-radius` may play into this as well? The Firefox screenshot above shows a double-border in the middle, despite the Inspector showing 0 right border. If I uncheck `border-radius`, in Firefox, it fixes that issue.

These properties should all be independent of one another. Why are they affecting each other?

### Edit

Trying to recreate in codepen. Unsuccessful so far, but it looks like it has something to do with `transform` - these inputs are in a container that is set with the following

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
@include transform(translate(-50%,-50%));
```

This has the effect of vertically and horizontally centering the element no matter the width or height in modern browsers. When I turn off `transform` the border shows up as it should. As I understand, `transform` accesses the GPU? Or it can? It seems quite possible that this is what's throwing it off. If you look at the screenshot, there are strange border artifacts (like, a partial, interior border on the right side of the left element) that I can't explain.

### Edit 2

It's got to be `transform` - changing the `border-color` to red makes this clear: the border is being rendered at a sub-pixel level and then, for some reason, cut off in a funky way. You can see a vague pink border around the left input:

[image: sub-pixel border]

Comment: @Paulie_D working on it - can't currently reproduce. But I have expanded my assessment. It appears to be linked to the `transform` attribute and sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help and without the fiddle, it's difficult to recreate; but I wanted to share something I've recently encountered with webkit browsers and Foundation.

By default, Foundation attaches a right float on the last column in each row or horizontal block...

foundation.css

```
  [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
float: right; }
```

99% of the time this is never an issue, unless you have a very small border between columns. Webkit browsers calculate percentages strangely at times.

You mentioned your columns were floated left, but just in case this is still an issue; overriding the above pseudo class to float the last-child column left may help.

Comment: This is a known issue with the way some browsers will calculate percentages that split pixels. It's definitely good for people to know, but it's pretty well-documented and unrelated to the problem discussed above. The reason Foundation floats the last item right is because they (I think somewhat reasonably) feel that it's better to have a potential 1px difference between elements than to have the right side of a grid be uneven.